# Iterating in HashMap of arraylists

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, hashset

Briefly - I try to write a method that should convert the values of `String[] sourceAllPeopleInMyFamily` to single objects of `Person`.
Then, check if this `Person` instance exists in `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Person>> allPeople`. If it does, I should add this `Person` instance to `HashSet<Person> allPeopleInMyFamily`.

`Person` class contains `String personName` + `int personAge`.
`HashMap<String, ArrayList<Person>>` contains the key `String personName` + the value `array list of Person objects`.

I wrote this following code.

Since I use `HashMap`, I use `entry` to iterate the all the map.
But since the entry checks all keys&values, this **prevents me to have a return statement** if the object isn't found.

Please advice is there any **better iteration** for my case?

```
    boolean addPerson (String[] sourceAllPeopleInMyFamily) {

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Person>> allPeople = pointer to another initialized HashMap in another package;

        HashSet<Person> allPeopleInMyFamily = new HashSet<Person>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Person>> entry : allPeople.entrySet()) {

            for (String sourcePersonInMyFamily : sourceAllPeopleInMyFamily) {

                Person personInMyFamily = new Person (sourcePersonInMyFamily); // Create a new person based on sourceAllPeopleInMyFamily array

                if (entry.getValue().contains(personInMyFamily) { // Check if personInMyFamily exists in all people set

                    if (!allPeopleInMyFamily.add(personInMyFamily))
                        return false;

                // } else { return false; } ???????

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point in having a key if you don't use it? What is that String and is your current data structure really useful if you can't use its advantages?

Comment: and what's the point of populating the hashset if it remains a local variable and is not visible outside of the method

Comment: @Tom These data structures are given to me, I cannot change it. I agree that this is not the wisest structure to use for this purpose. However, I must get the job done. I would really really appreciate it if you could suggest any other solution?

Comment: Not sure why you say, " this prevents me to have a return statement" ... In scenarios like this, you return true (early) from the innermost loop when you find what you were looking for, else exit from all loops and just return false there at the end...